# Remove text from a richtext box if checkbox is checked on button click

Tags: c#, winforms

Still new to C# and have been working on this program for sometime off and on added different features and what not. The program is for my job and it logs notes. Essentiall you type all the info into several different textboxes and then click a button and it combines the info into a large output richtextbox and adds some formatting to it and saves to a file and copies the info to the clipboard.

I'm wanting to set it up so that if i have a specific checkbox checked when i hit the button to process everything it will omit some of the formatting. I am using string builder to move the info into the output box.
Here is a sample of some of the code of how i have it working. Please let me know if anymore info is needed i will be happy to submit it.

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Starts the Stringbuilder
    System.Text.StringBuilder strBuilder = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    {
        string cbrSame = custBtnText.Text;
        if (cbrSameCbx.Checked)
        {
            custCbrText.Text = cbrSame;
        }

        //Writes textboxes to the stringbuilder
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 CX NAME: " + custNameText.Text);
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 BTN: " + custBtnText.Text);
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 CBR: " + custCbrText.Text);
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 MODEM: " + custModemText.Text);
        //Statements to write checkboxes to stringbuilder

        string checkBoxesLine = "\u2022 LIGHTS: ";

        foreach (Control control in pnlCheckBoxes.Controls)
        {
            if (control is CheckBox)
            {
                CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox)control;

                if (checkBox.Checked && checkBox.Tag is string)
                {
                    string checkBoxId = (string)checkBox.Tag;
                    checkBoxesLine += string.Format("{0}, ", checkBoxId);
                    checkBoxes = checkBoxesLine;
                }
            }
        }
        //Newline for checkboxes
        strBuilder.AppendLine(checkBoxesLine);
        strBuilder.AppendLine();

        //Continues textboxes to stringbuilder
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 TROUBLESHOOTING: " + tShootText.Text);
        strBuilder.AppendLine();
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 SERVICES OFFERED: " + svcsOfferedText.Text);
        strBuilder.AppendLine();
        strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 OTHER NOTES: " + otherNotesText.Text);
        notesViewText.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
        Clipboard.SetText(notesViewText.Text);
        //....
```

Essentially i want to add a feature if checkbox1 is checked on that button press it omits the custModemText.text along with the \u2022 MODEM: and also the same for the \u2022 LIGHTS: and the string checkBoxesLine.
I have searched for something to do this but i am honestly at a loss about HOW to go about it which is limiting my ability to search for solutions. I have a sinking feeling i am going to have to redo the way i am processing my data but am unsure so any help would be appreciated.

Also this is a Win Form

Comment: Why don't you simply put your `AppendLine` of the custModemText inside your `checkBox.Checked` condition ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do it you first check that the checkbox is checked or not. If it is checked then modify your text.

```
private void save_button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Add mandatory lines to a string.
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
    {
         // Append optional lines to the string.
    }
    else
    {
        // Do something.
    }
}
```

You don't need to do a foreach loop. Just check that checkbox on which you want to put condition.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I thought of this option and even tried to start some code this way and couldnt really figure out which way to go with it. I suppose what im asking is what is the best way to remove those lines of text from the richtextbox? I tried to use Replace without success. Any ideas?  Forgive my inexperience this is a learning project for me.

Comment: I don't know any way to remove specific text. You should then call `RichTextBox.Clear()` and then add again your text. I'm not sure I understand your problem :/

Comment: Heh yeh its a bit confusing. Essentially i want to be able to check the checkbox and it not add the Modem and Lights information into the output box but if i leave it unchecked it works as it does now. The practical use is sometimes i dont have Modem and Light info to put but the MODEM: and LIGHTS: text shows up in the output and i have to manually remove that text.

Comment: So why simple conditions doesn't work for you ? Before the condition, you append all mandatory lines, then you check the state of you box, if the box is `Checked`, then you append the optional lines, else, you don't.

Comment: @Luke Oh i see what you mean. I will try and implement that and see how it works out. Will post here with my results. Thanks

Comment: The solution was very simple thanks

`if (noModemChkbox.Checked)
                {


                }
                else
                {
                    strBuilder.AppendLine("\u2022 MODEM: " + custModemText.Text);
                    //Statements to write checkboxes to stringbuilder

                    //Newline for checkboxes
                    strBuilder.AppendLine(checkBoxesLine);
                    strBuilder.AppendLine();
                }`